# How to avoid frequent creation of objects in a loop in java?

Tags: java, android, performance, memory-management

e.g.
I have a need where my ArrayList should contain hashmap at each index, e.g.

```
Public class Testing {
  private ArrayList < < HashMap< String, String>> myData ;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    myData = new ArrayList < HashMap < String, String>>();
    initialize();
    //After initialize myData should contain different Hashmaps.
  }
  public static void initialize() {     
    for (int i= 0; i < 10 ;i++) {
      myMap = new HashMap();  //Bad because,creating Objects inside the loop.
      myMap.put("title", "abc"+i); //Adding i, just to show that new values are stored everytime
      myMap.put("name", "xyz"+i);
      myData.add(myMap);
    } 

  }
}
```

Above code will create hash map objects every time in the loop, 
what is the better way to do it, so that I can avoid creation of objects every time ?
I am using this code in Android , but I think this is more general and related to Java more.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid it?  Modern JVMs are *very* good at this. Do you have evidence that it's a problem for your application?

Comment: Ok , I am using this code in android , mobile operating system , here Garbage collector kicks in every now and then , so have to avoid creation of objects for performance and optimal usage of memory.

Comment: I don't believe the GC will kick in as a result of this code (assuming it compiled) even on a phone.

Comment: ok , considering that many experienced programmers are indicating that , this is not a bad way. I will not do any changes for my requirement Thanks everyone.

Comment: @sat if you use android, you should tag the question that way

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd , sure will take care about that in future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need a List of Maps, then that is what you will have to do, there is no way around that. (Actually there is, you could write a helper method that initializes the maps when first accessed and only access the map through that helper method, but I wouldn't really recommend that).

But you could rethink your design and use a different data structure, perhaps turn the Map / List relation around and use a [Guava `Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). That will only initialize the collections when they are needed, and you can save your initialization routine.

Also, a List of Maps can often be replaced by a List of custom objects. Depending on whether the keys are dynamic or not, a custom object may make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Usually clarity is more important than performance. In this example, having it compile would be an improvement. ;)

You are not creating enough objects to really matter, but one way to reduce its consumption is to use a POJO instead of a HashMap.

Comment: As I'm learning from my recent (and traumatic) foray into Android programming, clarity often has to take a back seat to performance. It makes the Baby Jesus cry.

Comment: Agreed. However, the GC on Android is awful. It's like stepping back into the late 90s.

Comment: compiling above code is not necessary for me , as it is just a snippet of code from my original code. Thanks once again , Will search for optimization in other methods :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's bad.

Since you want an `ArrayList<<HashMap<String, String>>`, there's nothing wrong. Even no bad smell:)